# Date format Error in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my current project I populate the selectable dates in jquery datepicker and everything's work fine in firefox and chrome. When It comes to IE, the datepicker component popped up, but the dates were not disabled. To check, I changed the date format to "2011/03/12", it works fine. My current date formate is "2011-03-12" and I can't change this as I am using this in many places. Is there a way to fix this problem in IE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Chrome, IE and Firefox: 
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/n43Gq/

I just disabled 2011-03-12, 2011-04-12 and 2011-05-12